# Java spring Boot, JPA , Hibernate, persist an object of type OBJECT

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have multiple entities that the user is going to create one of them on runtime 
is there any way to persist this object to database without knowing its type 
the list of entities is dynamic

Comment: what have you tried so far? Show you afford to solve the problem on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might want to read-up on is called [dynamic models](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/dynamic_model.html).

Its important to understand this is *not* a JPA portable solution and is specific to Hibernate.  Essentially we allow you to treat a map of name/value pairs as a model that can be saved as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> book = new HashMap<>();
book.put( "isbn", "9293-93939-392" );
book.put( "name", "James and the Giant Peach" );
book.put( "author", "Roald Dahl" );
session.save( "Book", book );
```

These are super useful for plugins or user-defined models from external resources that have no way to provide proper annotated or orm.xml based entity mapping models.